# How to lookup a field in an array of subdocuments in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I have an array of review objects like this :

```
   "reviews": {
        "author": "5e9167c5303a530023bcae42",
        "rate": 5,
        "spoiler": false,
        "content": "This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment.",
        "createdAt": "2020-04-12T16:08:34.966Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-12T16:08:34.966Z"
    },
```

What I want to achieve is to lookup the **author** field and get the user data, but the problem is that the lookup I am trying to use only returns this to me:

**Code :**

```
 .lookup({
    from: 'users',
    localField: 'reviews.author',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'reviews.author',
  })
```

**Response :**

### [image: Response of api]

Any way to get the author's data in that field? That's where the author's Id is.

Comment: From your comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199439/i-dont-understand-why-mongoose-converts-my-object-array-to-an-array?noredirect=1#comment108266926_61199439) -> What did you find missing/ what's that you're not able to understand in below answer ? I saw deleted comment *says working perfect* & un-accepted - if you can point out exactly what's going wrong I can help else please find a better answer & post it here I would learn from it to know what really went missing..!!

Comment: @whoami here is the question better, please review it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212927/how-to-make-a-lookup-of-the-author-field-of-various-arrays-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute below query on your database :

```
db.reviews.aggregate([
  /** unwind in general is not needed for `$lookup` for if you wanted to match lookup result with specific elem in array is needed */
  {
    $unwind: { path: "$reviews", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "reviews.author",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "author", // Pull lookup result into 'author' field
    },
  },
  /** Update 'reviews.author' field in 'reviews' object by checking if   'author' field got a match from 'users' collection.
   * If Yes - As lookup returns an array get first elem & assign(As there will be only one element returned -uniques),
   * If No - keep 'reviews.author' as is */
  {
    $addFields: {
      "reviews.author": {
        $cond: [
          { $ne: ["$author", []] },
          { $arrayElemAt: ["$author", 0] },
          "$reviews.author",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  /** Group back the documents based on '_id' field & push back all individual 'reviews' objects to 'reviews' array */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      reviews: { $push: "$reviews" },
    },
  },
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fe_2i8k55x7)

**Note :** Just in case if you've other fields in document along with `reviews` that needs to be preserved in output then starting at `$group` use these stages :

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      },
      reviews: {
        $push: "$reviews"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data.reviews": "$reviews"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "data.author": 0
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  }
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nmHe70bixY8)

**Note :** Try to keep queries to run on lesser datasets maybe by adding `$match` as first stage to filter documents & also have proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `populate('author')` method of mongoose on the request to the server which gets the id of that author and adds the user data to the response of mongoose 
and dont forget to set your schema in a way that these two collections are connected 
in your review schema you should add ref to the schema which the author user is saved 
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },

Comment: I can't use the .populate() method because I'm using .aggregate(). And the references in the model are correct, because with populate() it works perfectly for me, but with lookup it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this code**

```
$lookup:{
            from:'users',
            localField:'reviews.author',
            foreignField:'_id',
            as:'reviews.author'
        }
**OR**

> When You find the doc then use populate
> reviews.find().populate("author")
```

Comment: I can't use .populate() in a query aggregate().