# Merge 2 array objects into 1

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to merge objects within an array based on another array. What I have is,

Orders

```
{
   _id: 0,
   orderID: 1,
   entries: [
     { item_id: 43, quantity: 2  },
     { item_id: 2, quantity: 1}
   ]
}
```

Items

```
{
   _id: 43,
   item_name: "tshirt"

}
{
   _id: 2,
   item_name: "jeans"

}
```

After lookup I am getting the below document with 2 arrays - entries and items. I would like to have entries contain the corresponding item.

```
{
   _id: 0,
   orderID: 1,
   entries: [
     { item_id: 43, quantity: 2  },
     { item_id: 2, quantity: 1}
   ]
   items: [
    { item_id: 43, item_name: "tshirt"  },
    { item_id: 2, item_name: "jeans"  },
   ]
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
   _id: 0,
   orderID: 1,
   entries: [
     { item_id: 43, quantity: 2, item_name: "tshirt"  },
     { item_id: 2, quantity: 1, item_name: "jeans"}
   ]
}
```

I was able to achieve this by unwinding both arrays, addFields and then grouping as mentioned by @whoami.
See current pipeline: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rL-Lzmfuw9h

Is there any way to achieve this without unwinding?

Comment: Can you show your current pipeline?

Comment: @Farhan : Check this :: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177323/how-to-lookup-a-field-in-an-array-of-subdocuments-in-mongoose/61177645#61177645)  it might help you & I think that's what you're looking for !!

Comment: @whoami: Thank you, I was able to achieve this by unwinding, refer mongoplayground. However, is there a way to achieve this without unwinding the arrays?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar: Updated with monogplayground with current pipeline.