# How to make a lookup of the "Author" field of various arrays in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, join, mongoose, mongoose-populate

My problem is that I want to do a Lookup of the field "Author" for the array of objects "Reviews", "Followers" and "Watching" but I don't know why it gives me this result in the others arrays, that value repeats the same number of times of the documents in the "Reviews" array.

```
  .unwind({ path: '$reviews', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true })
  .lookup({
    from: 'users',
    let: { userId: '$reviews.author' },
    pipeline: [
      { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$userId'] } } },
      {
        $project: {
          name: 1,
          username: 1,
          photo: 1,
          rank: 1,
          'premium.status': 1,
          online: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
    as: 'reviews.author',
  })
  .unwind({ path: '$followers', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true })
  .lookup({
    from: 'users',
    let: { userId: '$followers.author' },
    pipeline: [
      { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$userId'] } } },
      {
        $project: {
          name: 1,
          username: 1,
          photo: 1,
          rank: 1,
          'premium.status': 1,
          online: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
    as: 'followers.author',
  })
  .unwind({ path: '$watching', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true })
  .lookup({
    from: 'users',
    let: { userId: '$watching.author' },
    pipeline: [
      { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$userId'] } } },
      {
        $project: {
          name: 1,
          username: 1,
          photo: 1,
          rank: 1,
          'premium.status': 1,
          online: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
    as: 'watching.author',
  })
  .group({
    _id: '$_id',
    data: {
      $first: '$$ROOT',
    },
    reviews: {
      $push: '$reviews',
    },
    followers: {
      $push: '$followers',
    },
    watching: {
      $push: '$watching',
    },
  })
```

> This is the result when "Reviews" has documents:

[image: This is the result when "Reviews" has documents]

The "Followers / Watching" array has nothing in the database but it is shown here in this way, repeating that value the same number of documents that are in reviews, I don't know what happens.

> And when all arrays are empty, this happens:

[image: And when all arrays are empty, this happens]

It keeps showing that, but I don't know how to repair it.

In summary, "Reviews", "Watching", and "Followers" have an "Author" field, and I want to do a lookup to the author field of watching, and also for followers and reviews but I have these problems. Please I need help.

> Example: This is how it looks in the database:

[image: Example: This is how it looks in the database]

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$unwind` stage creates a new document for every element in the array you are unwinding.  Each new document will contain a copy of every other field in the document.

If the original document looks like

```
{
  _id: "unique",
  Array1:["A","B","C"],
  Array2:["D","E","F"],
}
```

After unwinding "Array1", there will be 3 documents in the pipeline:

```
[
 {
   _id: "unique",
   Array1:"A",
   Array2:["D","E","F"]
 },{
   _id: "unique",
   Array1:"B",
   Array2:["D","E","F"]
 },{
   _id: "unique",
   Array1:"C",
   Array2:["D","E","F"]
 }
]
```

Then unwinding "watchers" will expand *each* of the watchers arrays so that you have the cartesian product of the arrays. [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3h2Ys1R_q62)

In your case, the original document has 2 reviews, but no followers and no watchers, so at the start of the pipeline contains one document, similar to:

```
[
  {
    _id: "ObjectId",
    data: "other data"
    reviews: [{content:"review1", author:"ObjectId"},
              {content:"review2", author:"ObjectId"}]
  }
]
```

After the first unwind, you have 2 documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: "ObjectId",
    data: "other data"
    reviews: {content:"review1", author:"ObjectId"}
  },
{
    _id: "ObjectId",
    data: "other data"
    reviews: {content:"review2", author:"ObjectId"}
  }
]
```

The first lookup replaces the author ID with data for each document, then the second unwind is applied to each document.

Since that array is empty, the lookup returns an empty array, and the third unwind is applied.
Just before the `$group` stage, the pipeline contains 2 documents with the arrays:

```
[
  {
    _id: "ObjectId",
    data: "other data"
    reviews: {content:"review1", author:"ObjectId"},
    followers: {author: []},
    watchers: {author: []}
  },
{
    _id: "ObjectId",
    data: "other data"
    reviews: {content:"review2", author:"ObjectId"},
    followers: {author:[]},
    watchers: {author: []}
  }
]
```

Since both documents have the same `_id` they are grouped together, with the final result containing the first document as "data".

For the arrays, as each document is encountered, the value of the corresponding field is pushed onto the array, resulting in each array having 2 values.

Comment: If you could be so kind as to please correct my code and be able to reach the desired result?

Comment: To keep from building the cartesian product, regroup after populating each array.